How can I upload a new version of a file to a SharePoint document library using the Graph SDK?
I'm using the MS Graph SDK to upload some documents to our corporate SharePoint site.  I can upload a document just fine using syntax like:
var driveItem = graphClient.Drives[*driveId*].Root.ItemWithPath(*file.Name*).Content.PutAsync(*stream*).Result;

I can use the same method to replace the file with a new file, but my requirement is not to overwrite the file that's already there, but instead to upload a new version.
First, I tried replacing the post operation I used for the initial file with a patch operation:
var driveItem =  graphClient.Drives[*driveId*].Root.ItemWithPath(*file.Name*).Content.PatchAsync(*stream*).Result;

....the patch operation just isn't available at this endpoint.
So I tried creating a requestBody to capture the change (content only, no metadata change!):
var requestBody = new DriveItem
    {
        Content = *file*
    };
var driveItem = graphClient.Drives[*driveId*].Items[*driveItemId*].PatchAsync(requestBody).Result;

This also fails.
How can I upload a new version of a file to a SharePoint library using the Graph SDK?

This worked for me. The itemId used in the second call is the Id of the file created in the first call.
private async static Task UploadFile()
{
    var authenticationProvider = new BaseBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider(new TokenProvider());
    var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);

    var response = await graphServiceClient
        .Drives["b!cQAGne73X02RW5qyDPL4skiS-tT2Lw1JmPAws8_FHnp8cknSG44lRZZUH3XKqrWN"]
        .Root
        .ItemWithPath("Hello World.txt")
        .Content
        .PutAsync(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello World")));

    Console.WriteLine("File uploaded");
}

private async static Task UpdateFile()
{
    var authenticationProvider = new BaseBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider(new TokenProvider());
    var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);

    var response = await graphServiceClient
        .Drives["b!cQAGne73X02RW5qyDPL4skiS-tT2Lw1JmPAws8_FHnp8cknSG44lRZZUH3XKqrWN"]
        .Items["01GGRIK46VMB4YFUDQIFHL3QGCPYK4IRQ6"]
        .Content
        .PutAsync(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello World (revised)")));

    Console.WriteLine("File updated");
}



I tried this code exactly as written, save for the param values.  I keep overwriting the same drive item.  I don't see versions.  I see that versioning is turned on in my SharePoint library instance.  Check-outs are not required.

I discovered that I was uploading our binary files incorrectly, resulting in a zero size file.  Each subsequent PUT would overwrite whatever was there.  Once I figured out how to PUT the file OK, the versions appeared!  Thanks for the quick response.
